# Bypassing memory management system in Linux, windows and OX

Tags: memory-management

I'm trying to research information about how to implement the memory management system in a DBSM. I know the theoretical part, but can't find anything about bypassing the memory management system in Linux, windows nor mac OX.

I'm trying to implement an efficient DBMS myself for fun. Which should be able to run on any common OS. In Database Systems The complete book, they discus the importance on fitting the relations/tables in adjacent sectors/blocks on hardware for faster read/write. But i can't seem to find anything when crawling the web. Is there a way to bypass the memory management system, such that I can write to specific locations on disk in such that the data saved there are placed on continuously blocks and so that the file system can recognize the data as a file?

I know that this is not a general coding question.

I'm used to write in C, C#, F#, ML, Python and a little gnu assembly.

For clarification I do not mean which DBMS should I use, I'm trying to implement the the DBSM myself.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Let say that I have one pages of size X and i want my memory management system to start writing it at block n and writing it to the next m block where X <= blocksize*(m+1). e.i. no segmentation. This is of course assuming that we know that all space given to the memory management system are free or it is capable of finding such m+1 blocks of free space.

Comment: Then write your own malloc/free implementation.